# Fetching FirstName, LastName, email and profile pic after you sign-in using google account

Tags: android, google-plus

I have a **SignIn** activity which enables user to sign in using google account and there is another activity **Employer** which will then fetch the user's basic info and display it.

My **SignIn** activity:

```
public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

//Signin employer_button
private SignInButton signInButton;

//Signing Options
private GoogleSignInOptions gso;

//google api client
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

//Signin constant to check the activity result
private int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private TextView mStatusTextView;

private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

// private TextView textViewName;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);

    //   textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id
            .coordinatorLayout);

    //Initializing google signin option
    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestProfile()
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    //Initializing signinbutton
    signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

    //Initializing google api client
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();


    //Setting onclick listener to signing employer_button
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);


}

private void signIn() {
    //Creating an intent
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);

    //Starting intent for result
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //If signin
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
       GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
        String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
        String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
        String personId = acct.getId();
        Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
        //Calling a new function to handle signin
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}


//After the signing we are calling this function
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    //If the login succeed
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        //Getting google account
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Selection.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

        //Displaying name and email
        //  textViewName.setText(acct.getDisplayName());


    } else {
        //If login fails
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(coordinatorLayout, "Login Failed!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
        snackbar.show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == signInButton) {
        //Calling signin
        signIn();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {


}
}
```

My **Employer** activity:

```
    public class EmployerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView username;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_employeractivity);

    username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);

 }
}
```

**Update**

my **Selection** activity

```
public class Selection extends AppCompatActivity {

Button employerButton, employeeButton;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);

    employerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.employerButton);
    employeeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.employeeButton);

    onSelection();
}

private void onSelection() {
            employerButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Selection.this, Employer.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            });

            employeeButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Selection.this, Employee.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.items, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item){
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case R.id.item_logout:
           loggedOut();
       return true;
       default:
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}

private void loggedOut() {

    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status){
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Selection.this, SignIn.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Get display name & pass to next activity

```
if (result.isSuccess()) {
    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Selection.class);
    intent.putExtra("displayName", acct.getDisplayName());
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

In your Section activity read & use like this

```
name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("displayName");
username .setText(name);
```

EDIT

If you need to update in another activity means, declare that field as public & access from here like this..

```
TargetClass class = new TargetClass();
class.name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name));
class.name.setText("hello");
```

Hope this may help you..

Comment: Yes this is working but I am calling a different activity name Selection, and I want to display the username on the other activity named EmployerActivity. I have updated my Selection code.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch **Selection** activity from **SignIn** `Activity` with the data using an `Intent` and pass the data along with it. Put data to the `Intent` using `putExtra()` method. Then, use `getIntent().getExtras()` in the `onCreate` method of the **Selection** `Activity`.

For detailed explanation- [Start Another Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Code-

**SignIn** `Activity`-

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //If signin
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        //Calling a new function to handle signin
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
//After the signing we are calling this function
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    //If the login succeed
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        //Getting google account
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Selection.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", acct.getDisplayName());
        intent.putExtra("email", acct.getEmail());
        intent.putExtra("profile_pic", acct.getPhotoUrl().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        //If login fails
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(coordinatorLayout, "Login Failed!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setActionTextColor(Color.RED);
        snackbar.show();
    }
}
```

This data is sent to the **Selection** `Activity` which can be stored until the **Employer** `Activity` is launched. When launching the Employer `Activity`, you can put the stored data to the Intent by using `putExtra()` and get the data in the **Employer** `Activity`.

**Selection** `Activity`-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);

    employerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.employerButton);
    employeeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.employeeButton);

    onSelection(getIntent().getExtras());
}

private void onSelection(Bundle extras) {
            String name=extras.getString("name");
            String email=extras.getString("email");
            String profile_pic=extras.getString("profile_pic");
            employerButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Selection.this, Employer.class);
                    i.putExtra("name", name);
                    i.putExtra("email", email);
                    i.putExtra("profile_pic", profile_pic);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            });

            employeeButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(Selection.this, Employee.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
```

**Employer** `Activity`-

```
public class EmployerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView username;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_employeractivity);

      Bundle extras= getIntent().getExtras();
      String name=extras.getString("name");
      String email=extras.getString("email");
      String profile_pic=extras.getString("profile_pic");
      username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
      username.setText(name);
      //Display Email and Profile Picture with other views.
      //Note profile_pic String is a URL/URI.
    }
}
```

Comment: There are two activities between SignIn and EmployerActivity and I want to display the details in Employeractivity. The flow is somewhat like this --> SignIn -> Selection -> Employer -> EmployerActivity. I want to display the details in the last activity after all the activities are done.

Comment: In Selection class it is giving error cant resolve symbol "acct" and **Employer** and **EmployerActivity** are two different classes **Employer** is called before **EmployerActivity** and after **Selection**

Comment: My bad. Edited the answer. Also, the EmployerActivity code is provided by you not the Employer. For the Employer class, the method will be the same. Pass the data via intent.putExtra() and get the data by getIntent().